# set minDate to avoid choosing enddate before start date in html input

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to **not** use datepicker and only use input with `type=date` to set the min date to prevent user from choosing end date before start date? I'm using the bootstrap admin theme: SB Admin 2.

```
    <div>
        <label> Start Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="from">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>End Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="to">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to listen for the change event on the `from` field and set its updated value to the `to` element. You can do it easilly with Jquery

```js
$("#from").change(function() {
  //when i select a new date in from field
  $("#to").attr({
    "min": $(this).val()
  });
  //i set the min attribute for the to field as the from one
});
$('#to').on('blur',function(){
  //let me check if the value is greater than the from one
  var from = new Date($('#from').val());
  var to = new Date($('#to').val());
  if(to<from){
      console.log('invalid value in to field');
      $('#to').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label> Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="from">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>End Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="to">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that works! But can i not allow the user to manually type the date in? Because still i can manually type in a date before the start for the end date. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @DivyaShree I have edited the snippet to add the logic requested. If the user types an invalid date the field get reset and a message appears in console.

Comment: hi, out of the topic, is there a chance to set calendar to 18 years before to avoid user to be less than 18 years old?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
        <label> Start Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="from" value="2021-01-01"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" disabled>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>End Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="to" value="2021-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" disabled>
    </div>
```